# Splitting output into two variables

Tags: bash

I am trying to read raspberry pi resolution using the tvservice command into two variables: X & Y.

When running:

```
tvservice --status | awk '{print $9}'
```

I am getting:

```
1920x1800
```

Which is exactly what I am looking for.

What I am trying to figure out, is how to split them into two bash variables where X=1920 and Y=1800 so I can use them later on in my script.

Comment: Most of the context is not really necessary as you seem to be asking: Given the string `1920x1800` how can I split it into `X` and `Y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following. Where simply we create 2 variables named `X` and `Y` and in spite of printing the `$9` we are splitting it with using `split` function of `awk` and then printing their 1st element for variable X and 2nd element for 2nd element.

```
X=$(tvservice --status | awk '{split($9,array,"x");print array[1]}')
Y=$(tvservice --status | awk '{split($9,array,"x");print array[2]}')
```